# Why ~ sign used before number?

Tags: tilde

I saw in many places that there some number is presenting with prefixing the ~ sign. Actually, I couldn't understand the reason why they use this special character before a number.

As an example- Every mobile PPI number is presenting with prefixing this special character ( ~403 ppi density ).

Comment: "*I saw in many places*" - where?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unrelated to programming

Comment: You can see here -https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_mi_a1_(mi_5x)-8776.php
Screenshot- http://prntscr.com/kw2jrr

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Common_use

Answer (score 1):

The tilde character (~) is often used before a number to indicate that it is an approximation.